# 2d numpy.array() comparing one string to all others, and repeated for each string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Supposed I have an input file with a list of strings (I'm using int's here for cleanliness), e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,...,n

I would like to generate a 2D numpy.array that looks like this:

```
a = [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], ..., [1,n]
```

And then repeat with each consecutive string, e.g.

```
a = [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [2,4], ..., [2,n], ...[n,n]
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) library. The `product` function seems to be what you are after

```
In [19]: list( product([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], repeat=2) )
Out[19]: 
[(1, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (1, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (2, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 2),
 (3, 3),
 (3, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (4, 1),
 (4, 2),
 (4, 3),
 (4, 4),
 (4, 5),
 (5, 1),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 3),
 (5, 4),
 (5, 5)]
```